# Change content menu responsively using CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would like to do a responsive menu using CSS only.

I'm trying to do something like that :
- Display a pictogram when width for that div is really small.
- Display a small text like 'Search' (without the pictogram) when there is a little bit more width available.
- Display a long text like 'Search whatever you want' when there is a little bit more width.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: it's complicated. A CSS only solution would consist of adding a class like so:

```
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

to elements in your DOM that should be hidden given a specific viewport size. Now that you have a little utility class, you can start adding media queries that affect your various classes and ids in your menu. Here's a bit of a snag, your `.hidden` class needs to be changed dynamically. Really, you'll end up having more classes like this:

```
.hidden-search-bar {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

all over your CSS file, each only applying in a certain media query. Another approach is to construct an entire grid system that uses utility classes like:

```
.col-large-display-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

so you can tell the browser that when it is in the `large-display` viewport size range it knows to hide anything with that class.

I'm sure there are more interesting ways to go about it but if you want to be able to have these classes carry over to other pages then you would need to be a bit more systematic. I would recommend looking at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to see how they handle that problem but they do use JavaScript (specifically [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) throughout the framework.